# what's the likely max length of apple ios purchase receipt-data?

Tags: iphone, database, cocoa-touch, ios4, in-app-purchase

Before beginning to test the iOS autorenewing purchases I need to prepare my server database. My question is simple. I just wanna know what size I should make the varchar field in my database.

Comment: Simply use TEXT, then it will always fit :)

Comment: I will need to recommend changes to a current API that's fully defined so need to get more specific.

Comment: Better use MEDIUMTEXT. I used TEXT but didnt fit well at one point.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was using a varchar (4096) to store my base64 encoded receipts.

But to be honest, I couldn't find anything regarding receipt length on the official documentation (or anywhere else). The only thing I did find [on Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1) was that the receipt content/format is subject to change:

*The contents and format of the store receipt is private and subject to change. Your application should not attempt to parse the receipt data directly. Use the mechanism described here to validate the receipt and retrieve the information stored inside it.*

So probably going for text instead of varchar really is the best option.

Comment: I store them on the server. My receipt size is `6340` bytes long (Mac App Store, with subscriptions).

Comment: i tested and found 4096 is not enough

Comment: I use ostringstream to auto apply the size.

Answer (score 11):

`receipt-data` could grow to be much larger due to it containing older subscription information.

In practice, typical size is probably under 10KB. But I've seen receipt-data as large as over 500KB in automated testing, due to repeatedly creating new subscriptions.

It's better to use varchar(max) or text where it's not bounded.

Comment: I have received larger than 64 kb

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL, it's safe to use **MEDIUMTEXT** which has capacity 16 MB.

We were using TEXT but didn't fit well at one point.

TEXT has only 64kb capacity but it's more likely that receipt size will be morethan this after repeated transactions. I only observed this after many transaction in sandbox mode.

> TINYTEXT: 255 characters - 255 B
>
> TEXT 65,535 bytes - 64kb
>
> MEDIUMTEXT: 16,777,215 - 16 MB
>
> GBTEXT: 65,535 characters - 64 MB
>
> KBLONGTEXT: 4,294,967,295 characters - 4 GB

Comment: Closest to MySQL MEDIUMTEXT(16,777,215 characters) in SQL Server is nvarchar(MAX) 536,870,912 characters

Answer (score 1):

After doing some simple math I figured out it was safe to use **MEDIUMTEXT** as each receipt size grows by the factor of ~2KB/transaction and so you would need more than 800 transactions to max out the size. 
Thus, considering a very safe use span of 10 years it'd require more than 80 transactions a month or roughly 7-8 transactions every month which won't be the case for most use-cases.

Comment: 800 * 2kb = 1.6mb, not 16mb...

Answer (score 0):

May be use `jsonb` to store the base64. It can hold as long as 1MB.

Comment: Has anyone tried gzipping the data before saving it?